# sales report showing empty in Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1.8

Couldn't found any records in sales report section. I'm using `magento 2.1.8`. Reports expect from Sales module is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry  i found the mistake while fetching the reports.I was keep on refreshing the statistics for last day ,when i refreshed lifetime statistics got the result perfectly.